# Does log4py work with chainsaw?

Tags: logging, log4j

We use log4cxx and it works great with [apache chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/) but does [log4py](http://sourceforge.net/projects/log4py/) work with chainsaw as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if writing log events to a log file using log4py, Apache Chainsaw can process any regular text formatted log file.

In Chainsaw's config screen, you can define a path to a log file using Apache Commons VFS file system support - sftp:// or file:// are commonly used, to remotely tail a log file, or tail a local log file, respectively.

Try out the latest developer snapshot, which has a lot of new features and bug fixes, available at: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Comment: We noticed that there is a XMLSocketReceiver. does this mean we can write a custom app to send xml messages to chainsaw configured with an XMLSocketReceiver or is this like a regular socket receiver but it writes to a text file in XML? We are hoping it is the former since we'd like to use chainsaw over the network with our app.

Comment: FYI - Found in log4cxx i could configure a XMLSocketAppender which kinda works with the XMLSocketReceiver but noticed that the messages from our app is showing up in the chainsaw-log tab instead of its own tab separated by host name. Wondering if there is any advise to get these messages to be on their own tab like when we use the normal socket appended.

Comment: It is the former - XMLSocketReceiver can be used to receive XML-formatted events over a TCP socket.  There is also UDPReceiver if you want to receive XML-formatted events over UDP.

Comment: As for the routing, look in Chainsaw's preferences dialog, the general section, Tab name/event routing expression.  The values in a logging event are used to route to a specific tab - so add hostname and application properties to what your app generates in order to route to a separate tab, or change the routing expression.

Comment: Can you advise on how to add hostname and application properties to our messages we send over XML? Are we to embed the field with each message or just an initialization message. Below is an example of what our log4cxx app is generating.

`<log4j:event logger="mycomp.xxx.MyCtrl" timestamp="1426201575287" level="TRACE" thread="0xb5720b90">

<log4j:message><![CDATA[ [src/MyCtrl.cc(1114)]  MYCOMP OPER not complete yet]]></log4j:message>
</log4j:event>`

Comment: Here is an example XML event with properties:
<log4j:event logger="org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.receivers.ReceiversHelper" timestamp="
1426363383972" level="DEBUG" thread="AWT-EventQueue-0">
<log4j:message><![CDATA[Located known Receiver class org.apache.log4j.net.UDPReceiver
]]></log4j:message>
<log4j:properties>
<log4j:data name="application" value="log"/>
<log4j:data name="group" value="chainsaw"/>
<log4j:data name="hostname" value="chainsaw"/>
<log4j:data name="log4jid" value="6"/>
<log4j:data name="marker" value="bark"/>
</log4j:properties>
</log4j:event>